# Can this equation give $A=A^\ast$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have this equation:
$$
(A-2I)(A^2-9I)=0 
$$$$
\rightarrow A^3-2A^2-9A+18I=0 /()^*
$$$$
\rightarrow (A^*)^3-2(A^*)^2-9A^*+18I=0
$$$$
\rightarrow A^3-2A^2-9A+18I=(A^*)^3-2(A^*)^2-9A^*+18I
$$
And got to this:
$$
(A^*)^3-2(A^*)^2-9A^*=A^3-2A^2-9A
$$

Could this mean that A is normal ($AA^*=A^*A$) or the other way around? and how?

Thanks.

Comment: If you take the adjoint of $A^3-2A^2-9A=0$, you will see that the first expression is also zero. So you are simply asking if $A^3-2A^2-9A=0$ implies that $A$ is normal. That seems rather unlikely, does it not?

Comment: You seem to have just simply asserted upon expansion of $(A-2I)(A^2-9I)$, you then set this equal to itself with $A$ replaced by $\operatorname{adj} A$. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: no, $A$ does not have to be normal.

A counterexample: take
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 1\\0 & 3 & 0\\0 & 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It satisfies the matrix equation, but $AA^T\ne A^TA$.

The equation you have 
$$
(A-2I)(A-3I)(A+3I)=0
$$
simply means that the polynomial $q(x)=(x-2)(x-3)(x+3)$ is annihilating. The conclusion you can get from the equation is that the matrix $A$ has eigenvalues among $2$, $3$ and $-3$ and is diagonalizable. However, it does not have to be *unitary* diagonalizable (=normal).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to the equation $A^3-2A^2-9A=0$ the adjoint operator to have the other identity so your question is to prove that if $A $is a root of $A^3-2A^2-9A$ than A is normal.

$A^3-2A^2-9A=A((A-I)^2-10I)=$

$A(A-(1+\sqrt{10})I)(A+(-1+\sqrt{10})I)=0$

So the roots are

$A_1=0$

$A_2= (1+\sqrt{10})I$

$A_3= (1-\sqrt{10})I$

That are all normal

Comment: See my edit, I changed it a little bit

Comment: Sorry but (A-2I)(A^2-9I)=A^3-2A^2-9A+18 I=0, how you can get the other equation?

Comment: See my question again

Comment: Sorry in this case I don’t know the answer